# How to break a long code line into multiple lines in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

In Python, we break a long line of code into multiple code lines with backslash like this.

```
a = 5
b = 11
print(str(a) + " plus " + \
      str(b) + " is " + \
      str(a + b))
# prints "5 plus 11 is 16"
```

How do we do that in NetLogo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NetLogo doesn't care about multiple lines except for comments (the comment marker ; only lasts to the end of the line). All of these are the same:

```
to testme
  ; single line
  let a 25 print a
  ; command per line
  let b 20
  print b
  ; unreadable
  let
  c
  15
  print
  c
end
```

Comment: Wow I didn't expect that at all, thank you.

Note: It also apparently works on lists!